# Marker Clusterer Plus not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am making an webapp using marker clusterer plus library, the code I'm using is:

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  markers=[]

  for (var i = 0; i < puntos.length; i++) {
    punto=puntos[i]
    posicion = new google.maps.LatLng(punto[0],punto[1]);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: posicion});
    markers.push(marker);
  }

  markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{      maxZoom:20,gridSize:45,averageCenter:true});
  console.log(markerCluster.clusters_)
```

The problem is that it prints in the console the markerCluster objects but it is empty with no clusters and when I call it again in the console it is already working so my question is if there is anyway to have the object markerCluster already initialized when I call it from the code so I can use its clusters from my code.

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/examples/events_example.html) in the documentation, it returns the number of clusters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustering is asynchronous.  If you listen for the "clusteringend" event, the clusters will be available:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "clusteringend", function(mc) {
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += mc.getClusters().length+ " clusters<br>";
  });
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_markerclustererplus_simple_example_clusterend.html)

Comment: It's just what I needed, perfect answer!