# Getting markerclusterer clusters

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am making a map with clusters and I want to show a list of clusters under it.

To get clusters, I tried to retrieve them from the object. But it doesn't work as I expected:

```
    // Initialize clusterer
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);

    // this logs an empty array
    var clusters = markerCluster.clusters_;
    console.log(clusters);

    // This logs array of clusters 
    setTimeout(function(){
        var clusters = markerCluster.clusters_;
        console.log(clusters);
    }, 500)
```

So I'm trying to figure out if there's an onload event or a callback function..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Marker Clusterer Plus not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672295/marker-clusterer-plus-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the clustering library you are using but basically, MarkerClusterer class is an extension of OverlayView.

Clustering is done once OverlayView has actually been added (OverlayView.onAdd method).

The first log you get, empty, means that the overlay has not yet been added. To my knowledge, there no event for overlay adding.

The best solution is to extend MarkerCluster class, overload onAdd method, send an event and then adding markers in the corresponding listener.